# How to inject(custructor) a spring bean into abstract mapper of Mapstruct?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am having below mapper class in which I want to use `CounterService`. I am trying constructor injection but that's not working and `null` is printing.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = CounterService.class, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public abstract class CarMapper {

    private CounterService counterService;

    public CarMapper(CounterService counterService) {
       this.counterService = counterService;
    }

    public abstract Car dtoToEntity(CarDto carDto);

    public CarDto entityToDto(Car car) {
        System.out.println(counterService)
        //....
        return carDto;
    }

}
```

Implementation class by `mapStruct`

```
@Component
public class CarMapperImpl extends CarMapper{

  @Override
  public Car dtoToEntity(CarDto carDto){
    //...
  }
}
```

If I use field injection using `@AutoWired`, that way it works fine. It means Spring doesn't support the constructor injection of `abstract` class. Is it because `abstract` class can't be instantiated directly and require a subclass to instantiate?
Is there any way `mapStruct` can create a constructor inside the implementation class as:

```
  public CarMapperImpl(CounterService counterService){
    super(counterService);
  }
```

That way, constructor injection should work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring. It was a deliberate decision done by the MapStruct team to not use super constructors.

What you can do though is to use setter injection.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = CounterService.class, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public abstract class CarMapper {

    private CounterService counterService;

    public abstract Car dtoToEntity(CarDto carDto);

    public CarDto entityToDto(Car car) {
        System.out.println(counterService)
        //....
        return carDto;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCounterService(CounterService counterService) {
        this.counterService = counterService;
    }

}
```

Comment: how to use this mapper in Spring? By changing interface to abstract class?

Comment: You just inject the mapper. The implementation is annotated with `@Component`

Comment: Will this be thread safe if I inject request-scoped bean into a singleton mapper this way?

Comment: Request scoped bean should be exposed through `@Context`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use setter injection you can do the same what Filip suggested and just use field injection. If you don't need a setter of course

Comment: Indeed field injection worked! But I needed to be explicit in adding injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR (or FIELD). This allowed one abstract class mapper to use another abstract class mapper just with the keyword "uses", Mapstruct has generated the injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Mapper Decorator like below. Also, always make sure to check the generated class.

```
@DecoratedWith(CarDecoratorMapper.class)
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CarMapper {

    Car dtoToEntity(CarDto carDto);
    CarDto entityToDto(Car car);

}

public abstract class CarDecoratorMapper implements CarMapper {

    @Autowired
    private CarMapper delegate;

    @Autowired
    private CounterService counterService;    

    public Car dtoToEntity(CarDto carDto) {
        Car car = delegate.dtoToEntity(carDto);
        car.setProperty(counterService.count(carDto));
    
        return car;
    }

    public CarDto entityToDto(Car car) {
        CarDto carDto = delegate.entityToDto(car);
        carDto.setProperty(counterService.countDto(car));

        return carDto;
    }
}
```