# Mapstruct - String manipulation, but only on one property

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. My custom logic applies to all String attributes, instead of just one, that I specified for target.

```
@ApiModel(value="ShopProduct")
@Data
public class ShopProductDTO {
    private String description;
    private String fullImagePath;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_product")
public class ShopProduct implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "desc")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "thumb_path")
    private String thumbPath;
//getters,setters
```

ImageMapper:

```
@Component
public class ImagePathMapper {

    AppConfig appConfig;

    public ImagePathMapper(AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    public String toFullImagePath(String thumbPath){
        return appConfig.getImagePath() + thumbPath;
    }
}
```

ShopProduct Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ImagePathMapper.class})
@Component
public interface ShopProductMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "fullImagePath", source = "thumbPath")
    ShopProductDTO shopProductToShopProductDTO(ShopProduct shopProduct);

}
```

The generated mapstruct class:

```
        ShopProductDTO shopProductDTO = new ShopProductDTO();

        shopProductDTO.setDescription( imagePathMapper.toFullImagePath( shopProduct.getName() ) );

        shopProductDTO.setFullImagePath( imagePathMapper.toFullImagePath( shopProduct.getThumbPath() ) );

}
```

Why is the description field also being used with toFullImagePath?

Shouldn't this "@Mapping(target = "fullImagePath", source = "thumbPath")" specify that I want fullImagePath changed only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how it works.

When you define a mapping, Mapstruct will try to map every property in the source object to the target object based mainly on [property name conventions](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#basic-mappings).

When you define a `@Mapping` annotation you are indicating *exceptions* to this basic mapping.

In your example, when you define this:

```java
@Mapping(target = "fullImagePath", source = "thumbPath")
```

You are indicating that the property `thumbPath` in the source object should be mapped to the `fullImagePath` in the destination object: it is necessary because they have different names and otherwise the map will not succeed.

On the other hand, when you define the `uses=ImagePathMapper.class` attribute you are instructing Mapstruct to convert every property defined as a certain `Class` type, `String` in this case, found in the source object: as long as all the fields defined in `ShopProduct` are `String`s this mapper will be applied for every property.

If you want to apply the mapper just for one field you can invoke a [custom mapping method](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-custom-mapping-method), or use [decorators](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators), or the [before and after mapping annotations](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after), like in the following example:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses=AppConfig.class, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public abstract class ShopProductMapper {

  abstract ShopProductDTO shopProductToShopProductDTO(ShopProduct shopProduct);

  @Autowired
  public void setAppConfig(AppConfig appConfig) {
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
  }

  @AfterMapping
  public void toFullImagePath(@MappingTarget ShopProductDTO shopProductDTO, ShopProduct shopProduct) {
    String thumbPath = shopProduct.getThumbPath();
    if (thumbPath != null) {
      shopProductDTO.setFullImagePath(appConfig.getImagePath() + thumbPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Please note in the example that you need to do several changes to your mapper in order to work properly with Spring: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451618/how-to-injectcustructor-a-spring-bean-into-abstract-mapper-of-mapstruct) and [this](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#injection-strategy).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.
Works great!

Comment: You are welcome Losmi! I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Comment: @jccampanero this can also be achieved with `@Named` and using `qualifiedByName` for the mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much @Filip, I must admit that I have never used it, but it looks really useful. Thanks again, I really appreciate the comment.